# cut off corners jquery mobile collapsible sets

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to cut off the top-left corner of a jquery mobile header in a collapsible set.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" id="one" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-corners="false">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="f" data-content-theme="f" class="cornered ui-collapsible-heading">
            <h3>Witness</h3>
            <p>Content for witness tab. Content for witness tab. Content for witness tab. Content for witness tab. Content for witness tab. Content for witness tab. </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e">
            <h3>Victim</h3>
            <p>Content for Victim tab. Content for victim tab. Content for Victim tab. Content for victim tab. Content for Victim tab. Content for victim tab. </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d">
            <h3>Information</h3>
            <p>25% of Chinese women have experienced domestic violence.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.cornered {
    width: 176px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid #30C2DF;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

After adding a little custom CSS I can make a cut off corner but I can't find where in the jquery.mobile.css to make the change, because if I add class=cornered to my div it just adds the cut off corner on the left side of the header and doesn't effect the header itself.

This approach also changed the width of the header in my collapsible set, and made the content drop behind the other headers when expanded (see photo for example).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution close to what I originally had.

I added:

```
.cornered1 {}

.cornered1 .ui-collapsible-heading
{
    height:0px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid #30C2DF;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

I then alternated the color of border-left for tabs to appear stacked on each other:

```
.cornered2 {}

.cornered2 .ui-collapsible-heading
{
    height:0px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid #de1f26;
    border-left: 40px solid #30C2DF;;
}
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile uses the `.ui-corner-*` classes to add rounded corners. One option you have is to remove the class on doc ready. An example would be `$("[data-role='collapsible-set']").removeClass("ui-corner-all");` Let me know if this works, or if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply asifrc. I tried adding the code you provided to my jquery.mobile.js and had no success.. I have data-corners="false" in the the div containing the collapsible set so I don't know if .ui-corner-* is interfering with it or not.